# What article should I use before the noun "handstand"?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, zero-article

What article(s) should I use before the noun "handstand"?

I read several example sentences with this word and found different options to choose from. I would like to know if they are all corrected and interchangeable. See examples below:

> a) This morning I practised my handstand. (I know, "my" is not technically an article, but I found this option as well, so I included it.)
>
> b) This morning I practised handstand.
>
> c) This morning I practised the handstand.
>
> d) This morning I practised a handstand.

Comment: Personally, I would use the plural - _I practised handstands_ or _I practised doing handstands_. _Practised a handstand_ suggests that I only did it once, which isn't much practice!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you try to convey.

If you talk about your handstand routine, progress, work, you can say "my handstand". If you talk about the exercise, the pose, the technique in general, you can say "the handstand". "A handstand" refers to one instance of this exercise, a repetition. "Do a handstand" is the usual collocation.

Unfortunately, I can't think of any example in which "handstand" without a determiner makes sense.

Comment: +1, I agree with you, though I think "I practised handstands" might be idiomatic.